# Android Java : Efficient redrawing for game?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I would like to know what's the most power-efficient/memory-efficient way to invalidate onDraw() method.  When my game is drawn every 50 miliseconds (using invalidate in a runnable), it looks smooth but I get GC_FOR_ALLOC size of 25% - 15%.  Is this bad or good, or am I worrying too much about nothing?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid allocations in your game loop.  You can use the DDMS allocation tracker to see what's allocating memory -- it'll show you the last N allocations.  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc

Comment: Ooh thank you, you just broadened my mind! Thank you very much

Comment: It looks like my biggest allocations are from nativeCreate in class byte[], allocated in android.graphics.Bitmap.  Does this mean my bitmap is too big or am I calling it too fast?

Comment: Nevermind, I need to ask a new question. Thanks~